# How to stop the UI thread in my app until other thread completes printing

Tags: android, multithreading, printing, bluetooth

Description:

- In my app, I need to print data using Bluetooth printer.
- The UI thread has to wait until the other thread dealing with printing
  completes its task
- The printing thread sets a value whether it is able to print or not

problem: The UI thread in the app is not waiting and its immediately getting the default status false

Where I am doing mistake in the following code?

UI thread:

```
private void printingStatus()
{
    if(printData.isPrintFinished())
        // do something
    else
        // do something
}
```

// PrintData class that executes printing in a different thread

```
    private boolean printFinished = false;
// UI thread asks this method whether printing is success or failure
public boolean isPrintFinished() {
    return printed;
}

public void setPrintFinished(boolean printed) {
    this.printed = printed;
}

public static interface IPrintFinished {
    public void onPrintFinished(boolean success);
}

public void printData() {
    sendDataToPrinter(context, contentToPrint, new IPrintFinished() {
        @Override
        public void setPrintFinished(boolean success) {
            if (success) {
                setPrintFinished(true);
                Logger.e("inside if success - printed"+printed);
            }
            setPrintFinished(false);
            Logger.e("printed outside if" + printed);
        }
    });
}
public static void sendDataToPrinter(final Context context, final contentDefinition contentToPrint, final IPrintFinished listener) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        // starts here the actual printing and gets a result
        int tmpResult;
          try {
              DataPrinter.getInstance().print(contentToPrint);
              try {
                  Thread.sleep(2000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  Logger.e("exceptpion:" + e);
              }
              tmpResult =  STATUS_PRINTED;
          } catch (TechnicalException e) {
              Logger.e("exceptpion:" + e);
              if (e.getMessage() != null && DataPrinter.ERROR_BLUETOOH_IS_DISABLED.equals(e.getMessage()))
                  tmpResult = STATUS_BLUETOOTH_DISABLED;
              else
                  tmpResult = STATUS_ERROR;
          }


          final int result = tmpResult;
          Logger.e("print result:"+result);
          new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

              @Override
              public void run() {

                  if(result == STATUS_PRINTED) {
                      if (listener != null) {
                          Logger.e("inside the listener status printed");
                          listener.onPrintFinished(true);
                      }
                  } else if (result == STATUS_BLUETOOTH_DISABLED) {
                      SimpleToast.showToast("bluetooth disabled");
                      if (listener != null) {
                          listener.onPrintFinished(false);
                      }
                  } else {
                      SimpleToast.showToast("cannot connect to printer");
                      if (listener != null) {
                          listener.onPrintFinished(false);
                      }
                  }
              }
          });

                Looper.loop();
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** hold your UI thread for sometime. That will result in [**ANR**](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) state. Its the main thread which handles UI components.

Comment: The user will be printing the content that is displayed on the screen. So the printing is triggered from the UI thread. 
In the code, once the status is received then another set of data has to be sent to the printer based on the previous printing status

Comment: @srinivasa To do network tasks, You should use a separate Thread or AsyncTask and communicate with UI thread for results.

Comment: @srinivasa if you want to prevent the user from doing anything while the printing is complete, you should use a blocking UI element - something like a Progress Dialog. It's modal, takes focus, and the user won't be able to do anything while waiting. When the print job is complete, you can dismiss the dialog.

Comment: Yes you are right. The printing task is done in a separate thread. Two sets of data have to be printed when user clicks on print. Second set of data is sent only when the first data set printing is success.

Comment: yes actually there is a progress dialog, I didn't add it here.

Comment: @srinivasa If you have 1 or 2 printing tasks, you can trigger AsyncTask in series but if you have multiple requests, you should either use Thread (which is hectic to manage) or use a Service (specifically IntentService).

Comment: Let me give you the scenario: actually i am developing a printing API that is used by an app for printing the data. When user clicks on print in the App then apps sends first set of data to the  API and waits for success or failure. If success then app sends second set of data.

Comment: Can you please give an example using intent service on how the UI thread is informed about the status?